# Delete a variable in a newly inserted row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, row

my project is about calculating the working time of employees.

**df:**

```
   Door Name                Time Last Name First Name
0   RDC_IN-1 2019-08-05 15:00:00     STARK       ARYA
1  RDC_OUT-1 2019-08-05 12:55:00     STARK       ARYA
2  RDC_OUT-1 2019-08-05 11:11:00     STARK       ARYA
3   RDC_IN-1 2019-08-05 10:13:00     STARK       ARYA
4  RDC_OUT-1 2019-08-05 09:10:00     STARK       ARYA
5  RDC_OUT-1 2019-08-05 09:10:00     STARK       ARYA
```

First I need to sort it by time then I need to check if the `Door Name` is identical in two consecutive rows and if the time difference between these two consecutive rows is lower than 5min or not.
If these two conditions are verified then I've to remove the second row, else if the two rows have the same variable and the time difference is above 5min, then I should insert a new row with another variable, for example, if I have two `RDC_IN-1` then I should insert between them a new line with the `Door Name` is `RDC_OUT-1`.
I've been able to do that, but the problem occurred when I tried to calculate the amount of time spent at work.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file_name='test.xlsx'
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime as dt

df= pd.DataFrame({'Time':[‘ 2019-08-05 15:00:00’, ‘ 2019-08-05 12:55:00’, ‘ 2019-08-05 11:11:00’, ‘ 2019-08-05 10:13:00’, ‘ 2019-08-05 09:10:00’,‘ 2019-08-05 09:10:00’],
 'Door Name':[ 'RDC_IN-1,'RDC_OUT-1', ,'RDC_OUT-1','RDC_IN-1','RDC_OUT-1', ,'RDC_OUT-1'],
 'name':['alex','alex','alex','alex','alex','alex']})

print(df)
df= df.sort_values(by='Time')
df.reset_index(inplace = True) 


Total='00:00:00'
idx=[]
l=len(df)
if l < 2:
    Total='00:00:00'

if l % 2 == 0:

    for i in range (len(df)):

        if i == 0:
            print ('index '+str(i)+' ok')
        elif (df['Door Name'][i] != df['Door Name'][i-1]):
            print('index '+str(i)+' ok')

        elif ((df['Door Name'][i] == df['Door Name'][i-1]) & ((df['Time'].iloc[i] - df['Time'].iloc[i-1]) > dt.timedelta(minutes=5))):
            df['Door Name']= df['Door Name'].map({'RDC_IN-1': 1, 'RDC_OUT-1': 0})
            # convert time stamp
            df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format="%H:%M:%S")

            # sort by time stamp
            df= df.sort_values(by='Time')

            # calculate difference to next row per column
            df_diff = df[['Time', 'Door Name']].diff(periods=-1)

            # select and copy relevant rows 
            df_add = df[(df_diff.Time < dt.timedelta(minutes=-5)) & (df_diff['Door Name'] ==0)].copy()

            # change the time stamp of copied rows
            df_add.loc[df_add['Door Name'] == 0, 'Time'] =  pd.to_datetime('05/08/2019 12:00:00', format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
            df_add.loc[df_add['Door Name'] == 1, 'Time'] =  pd.to_datetime('05/08/2019 14:00:00', format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")


            # switch the label of copied rows
            df_add['Door Name']= -(df['Door Name']-1)

            # change name to mark the new
            df_add['Last Name']= 'NEW_alex'
            df_add['First Name']= 'new_alex'
            df_add['name']= 'new_ALEX'

            # append existing data frame with new rows and sort by time stamp
            df = df.append(df_add ).sort_values(by='Time')

            # remap the door featuere
            df['Door Name']= df['Door Name'].map({1:'RDC_IN-1', 0:'RDC_OUT-1'})

        else:
            idx.append(i)

    df['Time Spent']=df['Time']
    df.drop(df.index[[idx]],inplace=True)

    for i in range (len(df)):                                
        df['diff'] = df['Time'].iloc[1::2].to_numpy() - df['Time'].iloc[::2]
#                print('\ndfff\n',df[['Time', 'Door Name', 'First Name', 'diff']])
        df['Time Spent']=df['Time']
        mydf=df
        Total = mydf['diff'].sum()
        print('Total: ',Total)
        mydf['WORK']=str(Total)
        mydf.drop_duplicates(subset='WORK', keep="first")
        mydf['WORK'] = mydf['WORK'].mask(mydf['WORK'].ne(mydf['WORK'].shift()).cumsum().duplicated(), '') 

print('df3 \n',mydf[['Door Name', 'Time','First Name', 'diff']])
```

**output:**

```
    Door Name                Time First Name     diff
0  RDC_OUT-1 2019-08-05 09:10:00       ARYA 01:03:00
2   RDC_IN-1 2019-08-05 10:13:00       ARYA      NaT
3  RDC_OUT-1 2019-08-05 11:11:00       ARYA 00:49:00
3   RDC_IN-1 2019-08-05 12:00:00   new_alex 00:49:00
4  RDC_OUT-1 2019-08-05 12:55:00       ARYA 02:05:00
5   RDC_IN-1 2019-08-05 15:00:00       ARYA      NaT
```

**desired output:**

```
    Door Name                Time First Name     diff
0  RDC_OUT-1 2019-08-05 09:10:00       ARYA 01:03:00
2   RDC_IN-1 2019-08-05 10:13:00       ARYA      NaT
3  RDC_OUT-1 2019-08-05 11:11:00       ARYA 00:49:00
3   RDC_IN-1 2019-08-05 12:00:00   new_alex      NaT
4  RDC_OUT-1 2019-08-05 12:55:00       ARYA 02:05:00
5   RDC_IN-1 2019-08-05 15:00:00       ARYA      NaT
```

I don't know why it copied `00:49:00` in `new_alex` row or how to remove it.

Comment: didnt't I answer this question just yesterday? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58949998/add-new-row-based-on-an-if-condition-via-python/58953592#58953592

Comment: now I need to calculate the time difference between the rows,  this code pastes the value from the column diff above the added row in the new row and it messes up the calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the answer I gave you yesterday and add

```
df['diff'] = df['Time'].diff()
df.loc[df.door == 'RDC_IN-1','diff'] = np.nan

# calculate cumsum
df.loc[df.door == 'RDC_OUT-1','diff'] = df.loc[df.door == 'RDC_OUT-1','diff'].cumsum()
```

at the end.

Also don`t forget to provide a working example df. No one enjoys to create data frame from posted outputs ;)

Comment: I'll edit my dataframe, sorry, but I need to calculate the difference between every two rows ((row4-row3) + (row2-row1))

Comment: so, you are building a time recording system - okay I'll edit my answer

Comment: btw, the hole point of using pandas data frame is to use indexing instead of confusing and computationally inefficient loops. Before you build a looped function I would always recommend you to check if there isn't already a function for this purpose.

Comment: so you mean instead of the ' for i in range (len(df)):  ' I should just use your code( without implementing it within a for loop)?

Comment: yes, you can skip the whole looping and instead use indexing and the functions that pandas provides. Way more efficient and better to understand.